# крашится программа при вызове метода класса указателя

Tags: c++11

Есть класс:

```
class button{
public:
    button();
    void Render();
};
```

и я делаю во так:

```
button *b = new button;
/*Тут я с ним что то делаю*/
b->Render(); // тут краш
```

И на вызове метода Render() присходит краш.
но при обычном вызове этого же метода всё ок.

```
button b;
b.Render(); // тут всё ок
```

Вывалите пж инфы почему подобное может происходить

Comment: Так ведь смотря что вы в этом `Render` делаете... А пока — "Доктор, у меня что-то болит... — Ну выпейте каких-нибудь таблеток!" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ну при обычном вызове (через точку) в нормально работает...

Comment: */\*Тут я с ним что то делаю\*/* — например, обнуляю указатель :) Вы хотите получить ответ - так задайте вопрос так, чтоб на него можно было ответить...

Comment: "что то" это я дергаю другие методы которые мне впадлу писать

Comment: "например, обнуляю указатель" зачем?

Comment: Чтобы происходил краш при вызове метода `Render`.

Comment: (-_-) так я и так его не обнуляю, мне не нужен краш